# Archive Validation works on iOS8, but not on iOS7, but runs on an iPhone4s

Tags: ios, app-store

So, I have an app that I pulled my hair out to get past an iOS8 deployment, and I finally got that into Testflight.

I really do want this app to run on iOS7 as well, and really see no reason why it cannot. However, for the life of me, I cannot get it past the Archive/Validate phase. It does run on my iPhone4s running iOS7.1 directly out of Xcode, so I don't see what the problem is.

I am using AlamoFire as a Target Dependency, but don't see why that would be a problem. However, my errors are in the picture below, since I can't select/copy the text on this stupid platform, so hopefully  you can read it.

[image: Archive Validation Errors]

Regarding the first error, something says that AlamoFire should have a minimum of 8.0. I don't get it. I've fixed all the settings such that Deployment Target is set to 7.1. It is also set to use the Base SDK of 7.1 SDK. *Everything* is set to 7.1!! Everything builds, and the build succeeds. Again, this app runs on my iOS7.1 iPhone 4s. So what gives?

The next error about Invalid Segment Alignment. I haven't a clue. This was a problem when building for iOS8, but as soon as I took care of the Position Independent Code settings it went away. Now it's back.

The next error is about the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO. I suspect this one is some result of something else not getting built. I had this error on the iOS8 build as well, but it went away when the other problems were addressed. I would like to know what is causing this error.

The error about Invalid Architecture says the targets and frameworks have to support arm64. These settings all say to build for all the architectures arm64, armv7, armv7s.

The last error is about the Position Independent Code thing. I got this on iOS8 initially, but followed the instructions about the settings in both targets and it went away. The settings haven't changed.

Every time I changed a setting I've done a Clean/Build.  I am out of clues to fix this platform. Why does this app run on an iOS7.1 iPhone4s and I can't get it past the Apple gods?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It appears that you cannot have the base SDK set below 8.0 if you are using Swift. However, it seems that changing that setting to 7.1 didn't take effect immediately. So, it didn't complain, still built, and I still don't know what happened there. Still built and ran on the iPhone4s.

The other issue is with Alamofire. It is an embedded framework, and that *only* works on 8.0 deployments. It is "embedded" because basically you include include the framework project into your main project as source code. Still, my question is why did it build and work on the iPhone4s?

So, what I had to do is *not* use Alamofire as a framework library. This meant that I had to put the source code in my app, forgo the "import Alamofire," and the use of Alamofire.* methods. The prefix of Alamofire disappears because it's now defined in the top level namespace. Fortunately, I only use Alamofire in one small file and the methods defined by Alamofire, such as "request", do not conflict with anything that I had already defined.

I'm still at a loss for why it compiled and installed on my iPhone4s directly from Xcode.

So, after I eliminated the Alamofire.framework target dependency, put the Alamofire.swift source code in my repository, and change my references to it, I was basically able to upload and get a valid binary out of it to, now Apple's, Testflight.